# url.action, jquery, and mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I'm building an application that will shutdown a server, ping that server, and notify the user if the server has been shutdown.  If it does not shutdown successfully, it allows the user to "Try Again".   I can get the application to process the logic correctly the first time but when I implement the "Try Again" feature, it does not reprocess the Shutdown action.  I think it must have something to do with caching but I don't know enough about it to know where to start looking.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

Controller

```
    //URL: Build/Progress  
    public ActionResult Progress()  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

////URL: Build/MoveDevice  
public ActionResult ShutdownStatus()  
{  
    ImageInfo ImageInfo = new ImageInfo();  
    FarmInfo FarmInfo = new FarmInfo();  
    ProgressModel ProgressModel = new ProgressModel();  

    if ((Session["ShutdownStatus"] as string) == "Success")  
    {  
        ProgressModel.ShutdownStatus = 1;  
        return View(ProgressModel);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        ImageInfo = svcImage.GetImageInfoByImageId(Session["ImageName"].ToString());  
        string Farm = ImageInfo.FarmId.ToString();  
        FarmInfo = svcFarm.GetFarmByFarmId(Farm);  
        svcImageSvc.ShutdownDevice(Session["Username"].ToString(), Session["Password"].ToString(), Session["Domain"].ToString(),  
            FarmInfo.farmName, ImageInfo.Device, ImageInfo.ImageHistory.Status, ImageInfo.PVSHost, ImageInfo.PVSAccount);  

        ProgressModel.ShutdownStatus = svcImageSvc.PingDevice(ImageInfo.Device);  
        return View(ProgressModel);  
    }  
}
```

Views (Progress.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>  

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">  
    Progress  
</asp:Content>  

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">  

</asp:Content>  

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">  
    <h1>Progress</h1>  
    <hr />  

    <!-- Shutdown Status -->  
    <div class="panel" id="panel1"><img src="../../Assets/Images/load.gif" /></div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $.get('<%= Url.Action("ShutdownStatus", "Build", null) %>',  
        function (data) {  
            $('#panel1').replaceWith(data);  
        });  
    </script>  

</asp:Content>  

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">  
</asp:Content>  

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="FooterContent" runat="server">  
</asp:Content>
```

View (ShutdownStatus.asxc)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PvsUtil.App.Core.Models.ProgressModel>" %>  

    <% using (Html.BeginForm())  
       { %>  
        <% if (Model.ShutdownStatus == 1)  
           { %>  
           <%: Session["ShutdownStatus"] = "Success" %>  
            <p>  
                Server shutdown succesfully  
            </p>  
            <% } %>  

        <% if (Model.ShutdownStatus == 2)  
            { %>  
            <p>Server did not shutdown within 1 minute.  Please check the server and try again.</p>  
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Try Again", "Progress", "Build") %>  
            <% } %>  

        <% if (Model.ShutdownStatus == 3)  
        { %>  
        <p>An error has occurred.  Please check the server and try again.</p>  
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Try Again", "Progress", "Build") %>  
        <% } %>  
     <% } %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the caching is actually being done by jQuery.  Change the $.get to a $.post and see if it works.  If it does, you can still use $.get, but you will need to set the option:

```
cache: false
```

HTH,
Brian

Comment: +1 Internet explorer especially likes to cache GET requests. The easiest way around it is usually to use POST instead. The HTTP spec says GET should only be used for requests that have no effect. Since this request is supposed to change the state of the server, it should definitely be a POST.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it, this should probably be a POST anyways.  I generally use GET to query information, and if I am doing anything that is expected to change the state of the website (or system), then it I tend to use POST.

Comment: SWEET!  post did the trick.  Thanks guys.  And you're right.  Chrome and Firefox were working fine.  IE7 was giving me problems

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[OutputCache( Location = OutputCacheLocation.None )]
```

to your controller (or each of the actions you don't want to be cached).

The other thing you want to do is wrap your javascript in a document.ready() handler.  That's not strictly necessary as your script occurs after the element that it references, but it's a good practice nonetheless -- and you could also move it to just above the closing body tag, but that's more of an optimization.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { // execute on document ready   
      $.get('<%= Url.Action("ShutdownStatus", "Build", null) %>',   
      function (data) {   
          $('#panel1').replaceWith(data);   
      });
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this info as well...very helpful in understanding the process